# How to make jquery toggle smoother

Tags: jquery

I have used the below Jquery code to toggle a div element. Toggle is finely working but it is not smooth in appearing. So What I request you people is to make it smoother and help me out from this annoying function.

```
function toggleDiv(footerExpanded) {
$("#"+footerExpanded).toggle();
}
```

Comment: As Ranald Lam mentions, this might be the case on some low-end mobile devices, which have difficulty processing JS animations. CSS3 animations, however, are hardware accelerated, which means they might run smoother on such devices. The down side is that older browsers do not support CSS3.

Comment: `.toggle()`, without parameters, simply displays or hides an element. You need to pass it a duration if you want an animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use duration like in below -

```
$("#"+footerExpanded).toggle( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
});
```

or just

```
$("#"+footerExpanded).toggle( "slow");
```

or

```
$("#"+footerExpanded).toggle(200);
$("#"+footerExpanded).toggle(100);
```

default is 400

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into CSS3 `transition-duration` and then just modifying the CSS within toggleDiv and CSS will handle the animation for you :)
From personal experience it is much smoother.

Answer (score 0):

Is this help?

```
function toggleDiv(footerExpanded) {
    $("#"+footerExpanded).toggle('slow','swing');
}
```